# F-Test not included in Two way anova

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I'm getting NAN values in my ANOVA table when I run this code. I believe the factors for column 'V3' are improperly sorted. Is that the issue?

I've also tried the OLS library in statsmodel (for python) but I was also getting some error about NaNs and infinite values.

```
data <- read.csv(file = 'dogs2.csv',header=FALSE, sep=",")
data
```

```
V1  V2  V3
ï»¿0.28 Dog 1   Isofluorane
0.3 Dog 1   Halothane
1.07    Dog 1   Cyclopropane
0.51    Dog 2   Isofluorane
0.39    Dog 2   Halothane
1.35    Dog 2   Cyclopropane
1   Dog 3   Isofluorane
0.63    Dog 3   Halothane
0.69    Dog 3   Cyclopropane
0.39    Dog 4   Isofluorane
0.68    Dog 4   Halothane
0.28    Dog 4   Cyclopropane
0.29    Dog 5   Isofluorane
0.38    Dog 5   Halothane
1.24    Dog 5   Cyclopropane
0.36    Dog 6   Isofluorane
0.21    Dog 6   Halothane
1.53    Dog 6   Cyclopropane
0.32    Dog 7   Isofluorane
0.88    Dog 7   Halothane
0.49    Dog 7   Cyclopropane
0.69    Dog 8   Isofluorane
0.39    Dog 8   Halothane
0.56    Dog 8   Cyclopropane
0.17    Dog 9   Isofluorane
0.51    Dog 9   Halothane
1.02    Dog 9   Cyclopropane
0.33    Dog 10  Isofluorane
0.32    Dog 10  Halothane
0.3 Dog 10  Cyclopropane
```

```
anova(lm(as.numeric(data$V1) ~ as.factor(data$V2) * as.factor(data$V3), data))
```

```
Warning message in anova.lm(lm(as.numeric(data$V1) ~ as.factor(data$V2) * as.factor(data$V3), :
"ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable"
Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
as.factor(data$V2)  9   268.9667    29.88519    NaN NaN
as.factor(data$V3)  2   168.4667    84.23333    NaN NaN
as.factor(data 2):.( V3)  18  827.5333    45.97407    NaN NaN
Residuals   0   0.0000  NaN NA  NA
```

I'm not sure why the F statistics are NaN.

EDIT: The ANOVA table is complete when I get rid of interaction from the model and use 'V2 + V3' instead of 'V2 * V3'. However, I'm certain that I want to measure interaction between these two variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: In anova.lm(g) : ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550288/r-in-anova-lmg-anova-f-tests-on-an-essentially-perfect-fit-are-unreliable)

Comment: I think maybe it has something to do with the fact that there is only one observation in each cell. Notice how each dog gets each treatment exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

```
aov(lm(as.numeric(data$V1) ~ as.factor(data$V2) * as.factor(data$V3), data))
```

One-way anova

Comment: We need a way to make R recognize the data as a block design experiment where individual subjects undergo multiple treatments in random order. Oh and didn't you mean '+' instead of '*' ?

Comment: It seems that the F statistic is equal to ( SS_V? / ( # of levels in V? - 1 ) ) / ( SS_Error / ( # of levels in V1 * # levels in V2 * (# of observations in each of combination in each cell - 1) ) ) . However since there is only 1 observation in each cell, we get a divide by zero error.

Comment: How do we get R to set the denominator of the F statistic to SS_(V2:V3) / ( ( # of levels in V1 - 1 ) * ( # levels in V2 -1 ) ) instead of what it currently is?

Comment: Two ways to mind. If you want to look at the statistical results in detail, you can look at the function's built-in code or split the data. I'm sorry if it did not help.

Comment: It's been a while, but yeah each treatment cell has exactly one observation which is a no-no. If `dof(Error) = n - a*b` where `a = 10` and `b = 3`, then of course we'll get a divide by zero error when computing the F statistic for interaction. We need some replication like [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550335/7854570) says so that we can increase `n`